# JTable regexFilter right int to filter first column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

what number in the regexFilter constructor for a JTable do i need to filter the first column? 0 or 1? e.g.

```
 ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(3);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(); 
    if(!fa.getCaseID().equals("*CASEID*")){
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(fa.getCaseID(),0));//filter first column
    }
    if(!fa.getState().equals("*ANY*")){
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(fa.getState(),4));//filter fifth column 
    }
    RowFilter<Object,Object> filter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
            sorter.setRowFilter(filter); 
            mTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky because it's not explicitly stated in the [RowFilter.regexFilter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29) docs, but you can infer from this snippet:

> Throws:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if regex is null 
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - if any of the indices **are < 0** 
>   `PatternSyntaxException` - if regex is not a valid regular expression.

Even `0` is a legal argument. Consequently the first column would be `0`.

Comment: Thank you. I feared it would be a really dumb question.

Comment: No, it's not a dumb question but easy to test though. Generally speaking indices in Java start at `0`, BUT if you see JDBC API, indices start counting from `1`, so it's not wrong to want to make sure first. @user3235683